# Url for HDFS file system

Tags: scala, hadoop, cloudera, bigdata

I have some data in HDFS `/user/Cloudera/Test/*`. I am very well able to see the records by running `hdfs -dfs -cat Test/*`.

Now the same file, I need it to be read as RDD in scala.
I have tried the following in scala shell.

```
val file = sc.textFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/Cloudera/Test")
```

Then I have written some filter and for loop to read the words. But when I use the `Println` at last, it says file not found.

Can anyone please help me know what would be the HDFS url in this case.
Note: I am using Cloudera CDH5.0 VM

Comment: so is `/user/Cloudera/Test/` a text file?? It seems more like a folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "quickstart.cloudera" and the port, use just the ip address:

```
val file = sc.textFile("hdfs://<ip>/user/Cloudera/Test")
```

Comment: Personally I would discourage the usage of IP addresses, simply because server IP addresses change whereas hostnames tend to be static.

Comment: val file = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost/user/Cloudera/temp.txt") throws error path does not exist

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to access your file in spark job then you can simply use URL

```
val file = sc.textFile("/user/Cloudera/Test")
```

Spark will automatically detect this file. You do not need to add localhost as prefix because spark job by default read them from HDFS directory.

Hope this solve your query.

Comment: It did not work. I am able to see the content by executing "hdfs dfs -cat hdfs:/user/cloudera/temp.txt"..... However, [ val file = sc.textFile("hdfs:/user/Cloudera/temp.txt")] throws the error Path does not exist.

Comment: Do not use HDfS as prefix if you are running your job in spark or Hadoop they will automatically search in HDfS for data file you do not need to mention it. Just keep it /user/Cloudera/temp.txt

Comment: If I use "/user/Cloudera/temp.txt" I get the this error - Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/Cloudera/temp.txt

Comment: Are you sure that C in /user/Cloudera/temp.txt is in capital actually the Cloudera  systems which I had used till now in all of them the cloudera folder inside user folder is in small letter. And if this is not the problem then I will suggest you to try for any other directory like /temp/temp.txt because the structure which I suggested you is working in my cluster.

Comment: Awesome! Changing Cloudera to cloudera worked. Did not realize that folder names are case sensitive. Thanks.