# Write data frame to HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a spark program on my Windows. I wanted to load the data from SQL to HDFS. I was able to load the data into the data frame and using below query to write it to HDFS (present on my cloudera VM ). Below is the syntax I found. Can some one please guide where to get my cloudera cluster details in my VM ? Like what to pass after `hdfs://` ?. I expect `/user/hdfs/test/` represents directory structure in below url.

```py
df.write.csv("hdfs://cluster/user/hdfs/test/example.csv")
```

Comment: What did you try until now? I see there is similar questions just by googling, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706343/url-for-hdfs-file-system).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.